# Can I install tacker component of openstack on compute node , with key components running on controller?

Tags: installation, openstack

I am trying to install tacker on my openstack lab environment and I have one controller and 7 compute nodes. I have keystone, nova, heat, glance and horizon and neutron on my controller and nova and neutron on my compute nodes.

I want to know the compatibility to install tacker in compute machine and if I do how will I link it to all my services running on controller.

Please help. 
Suggestions to install tacker using a different way are welcome.

Comment: Tacker is still in its infant stages. Could you please elaborate your use case for which you have to move tacker to compute node?

Comment: It's been 1 year since I have worked on Tacker. We used devstack to install Tacker on current Openstack setup. Edit your localrc file to manually add Tacker configuration and re-run the setup.

Comment: My controller machine is 24 GB Ram only hence running all primary services on it will slow it down as I have ram limitation. Hence was thinking of moving it to compute node! @btpbtp7

Comment: Maybe it is worth to read https://docs.openstack.org/tacker/latest/install/manual_installation.html